# Gradient is covariant or contravariant?

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, tensors, covariance

I read somewhere people write gradient in covariant form because of their proposes.
I think gradient expanded in covariant basis i , j , k so by invariance nature of vectors, component of gradient must be in contravariant form. However we know by transformation properties and chin rule we find it is a covariant vector. What is wrong with me ?
My second question is : if gradient has been written in covariant form, what is the contravariant form of gradient ? Thank you.

Comment: The differential $df$ is a covariant object, while the gradient $\nabla f$ is contravariant. In coordinates in fact you have $$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}dx^{k}\qquad \nabla{f}=g^{ik}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$

Comment: Cross-posted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/126740/2451