# Why does $\nabla f$ get a "contravariant" index?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, tensors

I know the gradient transforms covariantly under a change of basis, so I've been struggling with this, because I always see $\nabla f$ written as $f^i$ for a real-valued function $f$.

I know that using the metric isomorphism $g^{ij} f_j = f^i$ one typically associates to $df$ the gradient vector field (since $df(v) = \langle \nabla f, v \rangle$ where $\langle -,- \rangle$ is the metric-induced inner product).

However, I don't know how to reconcile the fact that the gradient transforms in a covariant fashion with the "contravariant" notation $f^i$ that we typically give vector fields.

Would someone please clear this up for me?

Comment: The gradient *is* contravariant, it's $df$ that transforms covariantly. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868819/gradient-is-covariant-or-contravariant

Comment: Well that certainly solves my understanding problem.  Thank you